# Curl request not working in PHP Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am implementing Cayan Payment API in my PHP Codeigniter application.
I need to hit this url

> http://192.168.100.211:8080/v1/pos?Action=EndOrder&Order=1000&Format=XML

by using Curl. When I hit above URL on the browser( Chrome/ Mozilla) device starts responding.But no luck via Curl.

Here is my Code

```
$url = "http://192.168.100.211:8080/v1/pos?Action=StartOrder&Order=1000&Format=XML";
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction: http://schemas.merchantwarehouse.com/genius/10/Reporting/DetailsByTransportKey',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$report=curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($report);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: i tried your code and got `"Could not connect to the server"`.Also URL directly in browser is not working at all, says:- `"This site can’t be reached"`

Comment: 192.168.100.211 is the IP Address of Cayan Genius device. It is currently connected to my LAN. You are getting an error because you are not connected with Device.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I don't think that you in the same intronet with OP :)

Comment: @hashkishor  add this code `if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
    echo PHP_EOL;
}` before `curl_close($ch);` and check for possible errors at your end

Comment: It is giving cURL error (7):
 Couldn't connect to server for me now.